# Calling an NSWorkspace Method Using AppleScript

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc, nsworkspace

Have been Googling for hours with absolutely no luck. Decided to post here as a last resort. I'm trying to access `setIcon:forFile:options:` of `NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace`. Take for example, the following code snippet:

```
set r to current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace's "setIcon:forFile:options:"
```

Upon execution of this snippet, the following error is thrown: `Can't get current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace's "setIcon:forFile:options:". Access not allowed. (-1723)`. I have tried a number of different ways to circumvent this strange exception, but none have worked thus far. Any suggestions on how to proceed here would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing strange about the error message. Have you actually looked at some AppleScript-Objc to see what commands look like? For instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/59097037/341994

Comment: Thanks for the resource. Using that syntax, the exception thrown is: `[<NSWorkspace 0x7f9849436590> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key setIcon. (-10000)`

Comment: Another example that sets the icon for an alias is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900620/10853463).  It might help to include the code that you are using, since the errors in your later comments are not from statements in your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (single) literal string parameter makes no sense. The [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1529882-seticon?language=objc) has three parameters. Each colon represents one parameter. You have to specify an `NSImage` instance, a string file path and an integer value as `options`

```
set theImage to current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfFile:"/fullpath/to/image.icns"
set success to current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace's setIcon:theImage  forFile:"/fullpath/to/file.ext" options:0
```

Comment: Thanks. My original intention was to add a `with parameters {theImage, theFile, 0}` statement following the method call, but I was never able to get that far. Upon compiling the new code, I'm getting `-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc6d8c5ff00`. Not really sure what to make of that.

Comment: `with parameters` is dead AppleScript Studio syntax. My suggested code doesn't affect `NSURL`. Both paths must be full valid string paths.